# Export search terms from Internal Search report on Sitecore 9.0.1

Tags: experience-analytics

Our client runs their marketing site on Sitecore 9.0.1 on Azure(PaaS). They want us to export the data they see on the table at the bottom of "Behavior/Internal Search" page of the Experience Analytics. Is there a built-in method to export the data in a CSV file?